# Is there a simple way to use LIKE in EF yet?

Tags: entity-framework, operators

Like is available via passing a string through ESQL... but not as an actual operator or method anywhere so far. I've found numerous articles suggesting work-arounds, the most [interesting](http://jendaperl.blogspot.com/2011/02/like-in-linq-to-entities.html) of which I get an exception on:

> NotSupportedException: The specified
>   method 'Boolean Like(System.String,
>   System.String)' on the type
>   'EF4.Extensions' cannot be translated
>   into a LINQ to Entities store
>   expression.

Anything here yet? EF 4.1 is out... any news or clean options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In EF 4.x, string.StartsWith, string.EndsWith, and string.Contains are translated to SQL LIKE. (Although neither support multiple wildcards...)

Comment: As I understand it, they don't support wild cards at all, so you are manually picking starts with, ends with, or contains via braching in code?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, @KristoferA is absolutely correct concerning SqlClient.
But this functionality depends on EF Provider. For example, Devart providers for Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQLite contain Like calls in the StartsWith, EndsWith and Contains String methods in both EF v1 and EF v4. Other providers may not contain Like support in EF v4 as well.